# How to fix beforesend ajax small loader inside individual row in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually, I am trying to create a table inside an individual row a small animation loader dynamically will come in laravel blade, if I click inside a row, the animation loader will show inside the specific row center point. But when I click inside the row the animation loader display in the table header, this is the main issue that I want to fix the problem, now I am facing a problem to solve this issue. How can I solve this problem please help me?

```js
$('.accordian-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find(".collapse.in")
        .not(this)
        .collapse('toggle')
    })


    function getVariation(){
      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{{url('get-ebay-variation')}}",
          data: {
              "_token" : "{{csrf_token()}}",
          },
          beforeSend: function () {
             $('#product_variation_loading').show();
          },

          complete: function () {
              $('#product_variation_loading').hide();
          }
      })
  }
```

```css
.variation_load {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.variation_load_tr{
    position: relative;
}

.variation_load{
    position: absolute;
}

.spin_loading {
    display: flex;
}
.spin_loading .dot {
    position: relative;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.spin_loading .dot::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
    animation: wave 2s ease-out infinite;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(1) {
    background: #7ef9ff;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(1)::before {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(2) {
    background: #89cff0;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(2)::before {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(3) {
    background: #4682b4;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(3)::before {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(4) {
    background: #0f52ba;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(4)::before {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(5) {
    background: #000080;
}
.spin_loading .dot:nth-child(5)::before {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes wave {
    50%, 75% {
        transform: scale(2.5);
    }
    80%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
table{
    width: 100%;
}
table thead tr th {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
table tbody tr td {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
table thead th {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
} 

table tbody tr td{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-top: 40px;">
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Catalogue ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Catagory</th>
        <th>Account</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr class="variation_load_tr" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="getVariation(this)" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
            <div id="product_variation_loading" class="variation_load" style="display: none;">
                <div class="spin_loading">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <td>15424181</td>
            <td>13463</td>
            <td>DIESEL BLACK GOLD JIPLAID Mens Parka</td>
            <td>Clothing, Shoes & Accessories>Men>Men's</td>
            <td>Topbrand</td>
          </tr>

          <!--hidden row -->
          <tr>
            <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow" style="padding: 0; background-color: #ccc">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>start Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>B7-1306</td>
                                <td>20.99</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>B7-1307</td>
                                <td>20.99</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--end hidden row -->

          <tr data-toggle="collapse"  style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getVariation(this)" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
            <div id="product_variation_loading" class="variation_load" style="display: none;">
                <div class="spin_loading">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <td>15424182</td>
            <td>13464</td>
            <td>DIESEL BLACK GOLD JIPLAID Mens </td>
            <td>Clothing, Shoes & Accessories>Men>Men's</td>
            <td>Topbrand</td>
          </tr>

          <!--hidden row -->
          <tr>
            <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow" style="padding: 0; background-color: #ccc">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>start Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>B7-1308</td>
                                <td>129.99</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>B7-1309</td>
                                <td>129.99</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--end hidden row -->

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, there are couple of issue on your code. Hope this will be helpful.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-top: 40px;">
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Catalogue ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Catagory</th>
        <th>Account</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr class="variation_load_tr" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="getVariation(this,0)" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
            
            <td>
            <div id="product_variation_loading0" class="variation_load" style="display: none;">
                <div class="spin_loading">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            15424181
            </td>
            <td>13463</td>
            <td>DIESEL BLACK GOLD JIPLAID Mens Parka</td>
            <td>Clothing, Shoes & Accessories>Men>Men's</td>
            <td>Topbrand</td>
          </tr>

          <!--hidden row -->
          <tr>
            <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow" style="padding: 0; background-color: #ccc">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>start Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>B7-1306</td>
                                <td>20.99</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>B7-1307</td>
                                <td>20.99</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--end hidden row -->

          <tr data-toggle="collapse"  style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getVariation(this,1)" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
            
            <td>
            <div id="product_variation_loading1" class="variation_load" style="display: none;">
                <div class="spin_loading">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            15424182
            </td>
            <td>13464</td>
            <td>DIESEL BLACK GOLD JIPLAID Mens </td>
            <td>Clothing, Shoes & Accessories>Men>Men's</td>
            <td>Topbrand</td>
          </tr>

          <!--hidden row -->
          <tr>
            <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow" style="padding: 0; background-color: #ccc">
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>start Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </tr> 
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>B7-1308</td>
                                <td>129.99</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>B7-1309</td>
                                <td>129.99</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                </div> 
            </td>
          </tr>
          <!--end hidden row -->

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

$('.accordian-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find(".collapse.in")
        .not(this)
        .collapse('toggle')
    })


    function getVariation(obj,id){
      $('.variation_load').hide();
      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "{{url('get-ebay-variation')}}",
          data: {
              "_token" : "{{csrf_token()}}",
          },
          beforeSend: function () {
             $('#product_variation_loading'+id).show();
          },

          complete: function () {
              $('#product_variation_loading'+id).hide();
          }
      })
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ej32fpw/2/

Comment: I tried to solve to make   id="product_variation_loading0" and onclick="getVariation(this,0)" dynamically but here, I have stuck. Would you help me to solve it? @Akram Hossain

Comment: @ Akram Hossain, you can check your code above you have given  <tr class="variation_load_tr" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="getVariation(this,0)" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">    
 <div id="product_variation_loading0" class="variation_load" style="display: none;">

Comment: Your question is not clear, if you generate this listing using loop, use loop index as 0 1 2 etc

Comment: But I am using laravel blade that's why this problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer, finally, I have solved this problem. @Akram Hossain